# SDL2 Compare textures

Tags: c++, memory, graphics, compare, sdl

I'm building a 2d graphical engine using SDL2 as the backend,
to reduce memory costs I wanted to create some sort global texture pool where every object could take a texture from.

To avoid duplicates I'd like to compare a new texture to already existing ones, is there a function to compare 2 textures in SDL2?

Comment: I don't think so. SDL2 textures are GPU based. SDL2 does not expose a lot of information about them.

Comment: Typically textures are uniquely identified by the filename. That sounds like the obvious key to "avoid  duplicates", surely?

Comment: @Botje i wanted to compare the raw texture in case the filename of the texture changed before a possible comparison.

Comment: Fair enough .. Then take a cryptographic digest (eg SHA256) of the image bytes *before* you upload it to the GPU and compare *that*.